# Top tags in country

Tags: support, tags

I have found a very interesting query that results the best users in the selected country: [Find top User for a Country for a specific Month/Year](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377074/find-top-user-for-a-country-for-a-specific-month-year?start=2015-10-01&end=2015-10-31&country=Belgium)

I'd like to find the most asked tags with the similar query. However I am not experienced in SQL neither unknowledgeable in StackOverflow inner database.

Comment: "Best" users?  How do you define *best*? Plus, I may not be where I say I am...I often use a VPN service that routes me through different countries.

Comment: As that *best users* query came [from this MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267968/find-top-user-for-a-country-for-a-specific-month-year) it is save to assume reputation is meant here @Paulie_D

Comment: Yeah....I suppose rep is the only measure we have...but it's a poor metric for "best" IMO.....there's a lot of upvoted cr*p out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/464894?country=belgium) for the number of questions per tag, for a given location of the user:

```
select t.tagname
     , u.location
     , count(*) as [# posts per tag/location]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where location like '%' + ##country:string## + '%' collate latin1_general_ci_ai
group by t.tagname
       , u.location
order by count(*) desc
```

By joining the `posts` table with `posttags` and `tags` you get how many times a specific tag is used. To determine the country we do a like where clause on the `location` column of `users`. The `users` and `posts` table can be joined on the `id` and the `owneruserid`.

On MSE there is an explanation of the [Data Dictonary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) as well as [other posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-data-explorer) to get you [started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239639/what-sede-examples-would-be-most-useful-to-new-users)

Comment: Don't you need to add `p.PostTypeId = 1` in the `where` clause to focus on questions only?

Comment: @Tunaki No, because posttags only has a foreignkey to posts for questions, adding the extra where clause would only hit an extra index without benefit.